# Powershell Script for Copying backup files and capture results in output file with specific details

Tags: backup, powershell

I have the below PowerShell script which is working for me to capture the results for one set of backup file but my requirement is to copy *10 or more* backups files in parallel to a shared location and capture the result and append the result to the result_log .CSV format....with the following result set....

Can someone help me modify the script to capture these results plz ? I am a newbie to PowerShell

```
DBName BackupPathAndName BackupSizeMB CopyStartDateTime CopyEndDateTime DurationSeconds
```

--Working Powershell Script

```
Start-Transcript
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String "Password"
$User = "UserName"
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$password
$item = get-item 'C:\Temp\BackupFileName.bak'
$time=Measure-Command -Expression {Copy-Item -literalpath 'C:\Temp\BackupFileName.bak' '\IP\Shared\TEST\BackupFileName.bak'}
$TransferRate = ($item.length/1024/1024) / $time.TotalSeconds
write-host "$TransferRate MB/Sec"
$result = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
Source = $item.fullname
TimeTaken = $time.TotalSeconds
TransferRateMBs = $TransferRate
}
$result|Export-Csv 'C:\temp\Result_Log.CSV' -Force -Append -NoTypeInformation
Stop-Transcript
```